# Instantiate ViewModels directly, without making use of ViewModelProviders.of method

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, dagger

I have a ViewModel called `RecipesViewModel`. Usually, I instantiated it this way:

```
RecipesViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
                return (T) new RecipesViewModel(recipesRepository);
            }
        }).get(RecipesViewModel.class);
```

But now I'm using dagger2 and so I put a `@Inject` annotation on the constructor of this ViewModel, so I'm able to inject it directly in my fragment, using field injector.

My question is: do I lose something starting the viewmodel this way instead of `ViewModelProviders.of` way? My ViewModel is already Scoped, so only one instance is create in context.

Other option is to move only the factory instantiation to a dagger2 module, but if there is no problem I prefer the first aproach.

-- EDIT --

Reading the documentation `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel`, I'm a little more afraid. Whe use ViewModelProviders.of to provide a Scope (fragment or activity). If I instantiate it directly what will be the Scope?

> ViewModel is a class that is responsible for preparing and managing
>   the data for an Activity or a Fragment. It also handles the
>   communication of the Activity / Fragment with the rest of the
>   application (e.g. calling the business logic classes).
>
> A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (an fragment
>   or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive.
>   E.g. if it is an Activity, until it is finished.
>
> In other words, this means that a ViewModel will not be destroyed if
>   its owner is destroyed for a configuration change (e.g. rotation). The
>   new instance of the owner will just re-connected to the existing
>   ViewModel.

-- /EDIT --

The RecipesViewModel code is showing below:

```
@PerActivity
public class RecipesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "RecipesViewModel";
    private final RecipesRepository recipesRepository;

    private LiveData<List<Recipe>> recipes = null;

    @Inject
    public RecipesViewModel(RecipesRepository recipesRepository) {
        this.recipesRepository = recipesRepository;
    }

    public final void loadAll() {
        recipes = recipesRepository.getRecipes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Recipe>> getRecipes() {
        return recipes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without experimenting and only reading from the docs and what I know about the architectural components, it all boils down to how you're managing the scope. If for example on configuration changes you create a new dagger component, than the view model provided by this component will definitely be different than the one you had before, because scopes are tied to components. What I get from the docs is that this doesn't happen if you use ``ViewModelProviders.of``. This will also not happen as long as the dagger component is the same - the viewmodel provided is also the same.

Comment: ViewModelProviders provides a storage which is scoped to the current Activity or fragment, and passed to the next instance on configuration changes. If you declare your ViewModel as a global singleton instead, it may cause issues because state will be shared between different activities or fragments instances, and also the ViewModel won't be destroyed with the Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 2):

For me right now (and I need to research this), but injecting a view model instead of using the ViewModelProviders functionality means you lose some easy activity-fragment communication.

For example [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing_data_between_fragments) they provide an example of an activity hosting 2 fragments. If one fragment needs to talk to another, the previous method was to maintain an interface via the activity who also had to take care of the lifecycle of that interface. Instead now you can just fetch it from the the ViewModelProviders 'repo' whenever you need.